# Unable to read a .txt file from website

Tags: java

My checkUpdate method is unable to read a basic text file from a website.

here is the code:

```
public String checkUpdate()
{
    Logger logger = getLogger();

    try {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(
                "http://www.spiromarshes.com/HighRollerVersion.txt").openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        String version = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream())).readLine();
        if (version.length() <= 7) {
            return version;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

It's just giving me the error: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.spiromarshes.com/HighRollerVersion.txt

Comment: Why are you doing a POST request? Also, you should in some way log the exception so you know what went wrong.

Comment: The error might be misleading since you are printing this out yourself. Please add a log statement for the actual exception itself. This may shed more light on the issue. I tried the URL on a browser and it returned `1.1` - which I think refers to the version.

Comment: It gave me this error: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.spiromarshes.com/HighRollerVersion.txt

Comment: That means that you are forbidden from performing that operation on that resource.  Try "GET" instead of "POST", since that operation corresponds to what you're actually trying to do.